# Did or Do in "Do you think it'd be okay if i did (do) that?"

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

> Do you think it'd be okay if i **did** that?
>   Do you think it'd be okay if i **do** that?

I usually prefer not using "Will", i'm kinda trying hard to use the **would** right.

Are both of the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same?

Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Related question at ELU: [First conditional with “would” instead of “will”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112582/first-conditional-with-would-instead-of-will)

Answer (score 1):

```
If I do that, do you think it will be ok?

If I did that, do you think it would it be ok?
```

But some native speakers will say:

```
  If I do that, do you think it would be ok?

   If I did that, do you think it will be ok?
```

There is "wiggle room" here. These sentences all mean much the same thing.

I don't believe the variation is dialect-driven. It's a question of idiolect.

Answer (score 0):

> — *Do you think it'd be okay if I did that?*  (Sticks with a **present simple question** and the **second conditional.**)

As for

> — *Do you think it'd be okay if I do that?*

by triggering the *if* clause (since the result clause is actually something to be done), you can't expect a conditional to do so. In this case you invoke the **first conditional** with the use of *will.* (An event that is eventually going to happen.)

> — *Do you think it'll be okay if I do that?*